# scrollOverflow: true on afterSlideLoad

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Using fullpage.js and Foundation, I want to set `scrollOverflow: false` to true if you are on a slide only.

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
    var loadedSlide = $(this); 
    if(slideIndex == 1){
      $fn.fullPage().setScrollOverflow(true);
    };
  }
})
```

Fairly new to this so if any more info is needed feel free to ask.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> In order to prevent fullpage.js from creating the scrollbar in certain sections or slides use the class `fp-noscroll`. For example: `<div class="section fp-noscroll">`

Comment: Alright thanks, this works but I wanted to remove the class and be able to scroll again when I click a button. Now it does remove the class on button click but it still wont scroll after. Do you know a fix for this or should I open another topic?

Comment: Call `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild()` after that.

Comment: It doesnt work like this?
`$('#removeclass.btn').on('click', function () {
        $('#details').removeClass('fp-noscroll');
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
    });`

Will try some other stuff too bc I need it on every 2nd slide,  mby something with slideIndex == 1) is better for me. Also with swiping on mobile etc.

Comment: Sorry can't help you more without a reproduction I'm afraid.